# Oracle fire a trigger before update

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have the table `product(id, product_name, value, old_value,...)`

Before updtaing the value of the product, I wanna fire a trigger to save the old value. For that, I created the following trigger:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER SET_OLDVALUE BEFORE update ON product
    FOR EACH ROW
        begin
             :new.OLD_VALUE = :old.VALUE;
        end;
```

But when I try to update the product table:

```
update product set value='newVal' where product_name='prodName';
```

I get this error:

```
 [Error Code: 4098, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-04098: trigger 'product.SET_OLDVALUE' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

Comment: What does `select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'SET_OLDVALUE'` tell you is actually wrong with the trigger?

Comment: I get this text: PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't generate that error. It gets `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "="...` as you have it in the question, and compiles properly with ShiriamM's correction. Are you sure that's the current code? How are you modifying it - as a script, or from within an IDE?

Comment: yes that's true I modified my triiger:
set :new.OLD_VALUE = :old.value; but without the set: I get this text: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ; indicator
The symbol ":= was inserted before "=" to continue.

Comment: Your question doesn't show `set` in the trigger; it isn't valid there. With `set` you get ORA-00922; without it you get PLS-00103, which is the error ShiriamM's answer fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is invalid because you are missing a colon (:)

Try this

```
         :new.OLD_VALUE := :old.VALUE;

create table product (
id      integer,
value   varchar2(10),
old_value varchar2(10)
);

CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER SET_OLDVALUE BEFORE update ON product
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
    begin
         :new.OLD_VALUE := :old.VALUE;
    end;

insert into product (id, value) values (1, 'SHRIRAM');

commit;

update product
set value = 'NEW NAME'
where id = 1;

commit;

select *
  from product;

1  | NEW NAME | SHRIRAM
```

Comment: This is what I tried and it works fine. Let me post my code by modifying my answer. The only different thing I would try is, check the data type for both, value and old_value, should be the same to avoid issues like this, referencing clause (for new and old) can be added to make it explicit. The other thing I noticed is your schema name and table name are product. I don't it is an issue. But generally I try avoid using the same name spaces.

Comment: Yes !! it's my fault, I changed my trigger to set :new.OLD_VALUE := :old.VALUE;